# Limit with inverse trigonometric functions: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan2x}{\sin3x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan^{-1}2x}{ \sin 3x}$$

What is the shortest way to do this please?

Is there a standard way to solve questions like that with inverse trigonometric functions?

P.S. I apologize to those who answered the earlier,  unedited version of this question which had included an arc tan term.  Since I'm new I made a mistake in the formatting there.  It's fixed now.  This is the one I originally meant.  Any answers please?

Comment: L hopital maybe? or you can consider the series expansions of $\tan^{-1}2x$ and $\sin 3x$

Comment: Taylor series? That's going to require you to know some classic Taylor expansions (or are willing to differentiate $\arctan$ to rederive them), but $\arctan u = u + o(u)$ at $0$, $\sin u = u + o(u)$ at $0$, so $\frac{\arctan 2x}{\sin 3x} = \frac{2x + o(x)}{3x+o(x)} = \frac{2+o(1)}{3+o(1)} \to \frac{2}{3}$ at $0$.

Answer (score 5):

If you know that
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin u}{u}=1,\\
&\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\arctan u}{u}=1,
\end{align}
$$ then you may write
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan2x}{ \sin 3x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan(2x)}{2x}\times\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3x}{\sin(3x)}\times \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x}{3x}= \color{red}{\frac23}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

As the form is $\frac{0}{0}$, we can apply LH rule
$$\implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan2x}{ \sin 3x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2}{(3\cos(3x))(1+4x^2)}$$
$$=\color{blue} {\frac{2}{3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint for small $x$ we can assume $$\arctan(x)\approx \sin(x)\approx x$$ which can be proved by Taylor expansion.

Comment: OP asked for some small trick so as L hospital was already stated i gave this as a hint

Comment: I have added from where this approximation came

Answer (score 1):

Using the following [equivalent infinitesimals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Equivalent_infinitesimal)
$$\arctan x\sim x$$
$$\sin x\sim x$$
We have
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan 2x}{\sin 3x}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2x}{3x}=\frac23$$

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\arctan x \sim x$ as $x \to 0$ we can take for granted the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1$$ Now let $x = \arctan t$

Then $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{\arctan t} = 1$$

The result $\frac 23$ follows, as shown in other answers.